I'm getting this error message in power bi, in the desk top version. 'system error occurred: Class not registered how do i fix?
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The following system error occurred:  Class not registered -- I get this in the desktop app of powerBI. I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times. I've tried to upload the csv in different ways. help!
'.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times. I've tried to upload the csv in different ways. help!
